# Regex that matches word-characters inside quotes "example"?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches word-characters + white characters enclosed in certain symbols EG: quotes.

EG:

```
one "two" three four "five six"
```

My regex should match "two" and "five six"

I'm trying with `/^(\"\w+\")/` and similar ones but I cannot manage to do it.

How can I find regexes enclosed in particular symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `^` anchor. `^` will restrict matches to the beginning of the string. Also you don't need to escape the double quotes: `\"` → `"`.

Change `\w+` to `.+?` or `[^"]*` to match whitespace.

```
/(".*?")/
```

Comment: Sorry there was an answer in my question, the word-characters inside the quotes can have whitespaces. Could you edit the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$str = 'one " two test " three four "five" six';

preg_match_all('/"(?P<words>\s*\w+[\s\w\s]*)"/',$str,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match['words']);
```

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: Sorry there was an answer in my question, the word-characters inside the quotes can have whitespaces. Could you edit the answer?

Comment: Edited the answer please check it

Comment: I could make it work, the only problem is that the result is returned as a subarray of match, how can I simply save results in match?

Comment: `$new_var = $match['words'];` Is that ok ?

Answer (score -1):

```
regexp("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\'\"]$/i",$variable_name)
```